# How to restore bookmarks before accidentally syncing Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-lion, bookmarks

I accidentally lost all of my bookmarks by signing into Chrome.

How do I restore my bookmarks?

I do not have the path:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```

Reference: Mac OS Lion

Comment: I don't think Google is following this site actively.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome backs up your bookmarks when you start up the app, so as long as you haven't closed and started up Chrome since losing them, you can usually find the backup file at (as you mentioned)

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak
```

Rename that file to `Bookmarks` (I would make a copy of the existing `Bookmarks` and `Bookmarks.bak` files elsewhere on the computer, just in case), and quit and restart Chrome, and they should be restored.

In my case, I had deleted bookmarks on a computer I was using temporarily, after logging in my account to Chrome and not disabling the login properly (in the settings tab) afterwards. This made it so that when I logged in to my other computer, the blank slate was synced over my existing bookmarks. Even using the recovery method above, they will simply be erased again. What ended up working for me was logging out completely (in the settings tab), renaming the backup file to `Bookmarks`, restarting, and then logging in again. Then my bookmarks remained.

As for your issue with finding the file, I would try something like

```
$ find ~/Library/Application\ Support -name Bookmarks.bak
```

in the terminal.

I realize this question is quite old now, but as this page came up when I had the problem myself, I figured I'd share what I found [here](http://www.kikawebdesign.com/blog/mac-tutorial-how-to-recover-deleted-bookmarks-in-chrome/) and on my own.